# PCB design tips for high frequency inductive load

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, stepper-motor

I am designing a circuit to control 4.5A stepper motors, that is, the tracks are thick and current will flow through them in both directions at high frequency.

My question is if there is a problem in putting the tracks very close to each other (separation of 0.3mm) or if there is any other tip that should be taken into account when handling inductive loads.

I would appreciate if you know any books or documentation about PCB design for inductive loads

Answer (score 2):

- make each current loop as small an area as possible and use guard tracks between to reduce crosstalk with shielded twisted pair cables and consider high mu CM chokes for EMI.